# Frontier: What is trait LinearCostPrecompile about?

Tags: evm, frontier, precompile

So it's often seen in `Precompile` implementations as a trait bound :

```rust
impl<T: LinearCostPrecompile> Precompile for T {
```

and the trait itself :

```rust
pub trait LinearCostPrecompile {
    const BASE: u64;
    const WORD: u64;

    fn execute(
        input: &[u8],
        cost: u64,
    ) -> core::result::Result<(ExitSucceed, Vec<u8>), PrecompileFailure>;
}
```

Can someone explain the why and what of this trait?

Comment: Putting this as a comment because I'm not that sure about the answer but I think the idea of that trait is to tell that a precompile has a simple (linear) way to calculate its final cost (inside the EVM).